# Is modyfying the referenced object affecting the original object from which the new object was created?

Tags: java, object, reference

I have a problem with understanding one thing.

I have:

```
List<Map> resultList = new ArrayList<Map>();
```

Then this `resultList` is filled with some data

```
resultList.addAll(somemethod(something, something, else));
```

Later in the method I have this kind of code:

```
Map timeSpan = someMethod(resultList, date);
timeSpan.put(KEY_ART, VALUE_ART);
timeSpan.put(KEY_TIMESPAN, true);
```

So I have a question now. If `Map timeSpan` is a map referenced to an element of `List<Map> resultList`, is using the `put()` method on the `timeSpan` map affecting the element in `resultList`?

I am asking this question cause a collegue told me that this is working this way - modifying an element in `timeSpan` is also modyfying this element in `resultList`. She is far more experienced, and I don't just want to believe her but I want to understand why it is working this way.

Comment: Your colleague is right.  You are fetching the same object, and editing it. As this same object exists in multiple collections, when you change it, you are changing it in all the places it is contained

Comment: I hope somemethod from 1st invocation is returning a collection of `Map`s and somemethod from 2nd invocation is just returning a `Map`, its a bit confusing to have same name for the method although their arguments count dictates that they're different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that `resultList` is a *reference* to an object.  You can copy this reference around and use it in many way, in many places but there is only one object.  This means when you alter the object, there is only one view of this object.

Answer (score 1):

Java objects are always instantiated as a reference to a memory space. If you create a second object from the first object, both will point to the same memory space:

```
Map a = new HashMap();
Map B=b = a;
```

Here, we first create an instance A which points to a HashMap which is created somewhere in memory. Next, we create an instance of Map b and have it reference to the same memory space as Map a. Now, when we change map b, these changes will also be made to Map a, since they point to the same memory construct.

In you case, you have a List this in itself is a memory construct. Each item in the list references a seperate Map. These are each also created somewhere in memory. The moment you retreive a Map from the list, you retreive the reference to the memory space where the actual map is located. After that, it works exactly as the example.

Answer (score 0):

`addAll()` will copy all the elements to the current list from the Collection/List you passed as an argument to this method. In your case, as each element is a reference to `Map` object, after copying, you have 2 references pointing to same `Map` object, so changes done using any one reference are visible through the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, put() for timeSpan is affecting resultList, because when a method returns a Map, which is got from the List, it returns a reference to the heap where map elements are located.